# Copy Table Value On Click To Another Page Input using PHP

Tags: php

I have a complex task to do, which I hope can be done using PHP. I have the HTML below, where I need to click on the '#link', copy value of '#code', save it using session_start() and then, once page has changed, dynamically create value attribute for the input (page2) which will contain copied from previous page value.

Could you please suggest best way to implement such action?

```
page1

    <tr>
      <td id="code">Value To Copy<td>
      <td id="link"><a href="page2.php">Some Value</a></td>
    <tr>

page2

     <input type="text" />
```

Comment: Unless it's homework, it looks like a mighty inefficient thing to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**page1**

```
<?php session_start();?>
<tr>
  <td id="code">Value To Copy<td>
  <td id="link"><a href="page2.php">Some Value</a></td>
<tr>        
//  Store code value in session and call session_start() before any output happened    
$_SESSION["code"]=$code_value;
```

And finally show code value in page2 input field

**page2**

```
<?php session_start();?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["code"];?>/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!